# Highlight commands inside lstlisting algorithm

Tags: listings, algorithms

I'm writing an algorithm with lstlisting

This is the output

[image]

And this is the code:

```
\begin{figure}
\begin{lstlisting}[mathescape=true]
INPUT: Insieme $C$ di cubi che coprono una funzione $f$
OUTPUT: Insieme $D$ di cubi disgiunti che coprono $f$

$D = \emptyset$
while($C \neq \emptyset$):
    BUILD-SOP($C$, $P$) # crea SOP e la inserisce in $P$
    $A\ = \{d\in P\ |\ \forall c \in P \backslash \{d\} : d \cap c = \emptyset \}$
    $D = D \cup A$
    $P = P \backslash A$
    WEIGHT($P$)
    SORP($P$)
    $B = \emptyset$
    while($P\neq \emptyset$):
        $p = P[0]$
        $P = P \backslash \{p\}$
        $D = D \cup \{p\}$
        forall $q \in P\ :\ p \cap q = \emptyset$:
            $P = P \backslash \{q\}$
            BREAK($q$,$p$,$Q$)
            OPT($q$,$Q$,$P$,$B$)
        forall $r \in B\ :\ p \cap r \neq \emptyset$:
            $B = B \backslash \{r\}$
            BREAK($r$,$p$,$Q$)
            $B = B \cup Q$
    $C = B$

\end{lstlisting}
\caption{Algoritmo DSOP}
\end{figure}
```

How can I make the commands like "while","if" and "forall" in bold and the functions that are written in capital letters in a way that distinguishes them from the rest of the code?

Comment: This is not really a listing, it is pseudocode. There are various packages for pseudocode that highlight keywords such as forall and while, see for example [`algorithm2e`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/algorithm2e/doc/algorithm2e.pdf) or [`algorithmicx`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/algorithmicx/algorithmicx.pdf).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment, there are better alternatives for typesetting pseudo-code or algorithms. If you still want to stick to the `listings` package, you could use the following options for formatting:

```
\lstset{
    alsoletter={-},
    keywords=[1]{while,if,forall},
    keywords=[2]{BUILD-SOP,WEIGHT,SORP,BREAK, OPT},
    keywordstyle=[1]{\bfseries},
    keywordstyle=[2]{\slshape},
    columns=flexible
}
```

`alsoletter={-}` makes `listings` treat the hyphen character as if it were a letter, so you can use it in keywords/identifiers more easily. Then the `keywords` option defines a set of special keywords (each set denoted by a number in square brackets), for which different styles can be assigned via the `keywordstyle` option. More fancy styles are possible; `listings` e.g. allows to give a separate style for all words/identifiers beside the defined keywords.

Finally, I suggest to use `columns=flexible` for listings with proportional fonts, as this makes identifiers have their natural width and so prevents bad innerword spacing.

The above setting applied to your example results in:

[image]

Comment: Where do I put the "\lstset" in order for it to affect just that block of code?

Comment: @GerardoZinno `\lstset` sets the options globally. If you want it only for a certain listing, you can use the optional argument of `\begin{lstlisting}[...]`